# Targeting pre-lollipop devices using Renderscript from NDK C++

Tags: android, android-ndk, renderscript

I would like to use Renderscript from C++ code that I compile using the Android NDK. I built the "HelloComputeNDK" sample that ships with the NDK. It runs fine on Lollipop devices, but crashes on KitKat (4.4.4) with the following message on `adb logcat`:

```
E/bcinfo  (28302): Invalid API version: 21 is out of range ('11' - '19')
E/RenderScript(28302): Failed to translate bitcode from version: 21
E/rsC++   (28302): Internal error: Object id 0.
F/libc    (28302): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 28317 (hellocomputendk)
I/DEBUG   (  363): Build fingerprint: 'htc/bm/htc_m8:4.4.4/KTU84P/401507.4:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  363): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  363): pid: 28302, tid: 28317, name: hellocomputendk      >>> com.example.android.rs.hellocomputendk <<<
I/DEBUG   (  363): debuggerd: checkTellHTCSettings
I/DEBUG   (  363): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
```

I have set `minSdkVersion="14"` in AndroidManifest.xml, `APP_PLATFORM := android-19` in Application.mk, and `TARGET_PLATFORM := android-19` in Android.mk. I build the sample using:

```
android update project --name HelloComputeNDK --path . --target android-19
ndk-build clean
ndk-build -d
ant -verbose debug install
```

I have seen similar crashes discussed elsewhere, but the problem in those cases was a missing `APP_PLATFORM` or `TARGET_PLATFORM`. This does does not appear to be the problem here.

I believe I have the same problem as this person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704847/ndk-sample-project-hellocomputendk-crashes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705350/ndk-sample-project-hellocomputendk-problems. I think that question got downvoted because the user posted two that appeared to be duplicates. I have the same problem and I believe it is a legitimate question so I am asking it here.

#### Edit

I am using SDK build tools version 21.1.2 and NDK r10d.

#### Edit after Larry Schiefer answer

I also tried adding the following in project.properties:

```
renderscript.target=19
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

This gives the error "sdklib.build.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK" because the HelloComputeNDK example explictly includes the RenderScript support library in "Android.mk":

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := RSSupport
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SYSROOT_LINK)/usr/lib/rs/lib$(LOCAL_MODULE)$(TARGET_SONAME_EXTENSION)
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If I remove those lines from Android.mk the example builds and install successfully and I get the same API 21 crash as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in ndk-build which doesn't pass "-target-api 19" to llvm-rs-cc.  Since the first RS support in NDK r9b, the RenderScript host tools (bcc_compat, llvm-rs-c, etc, compiled from K branch, API 19) weren't updated until r10c when they were rebuilt from L branch (API 21).  Without the explicit option "-target-api N", llvm-rs-cc in r10c+ uses the default API which is 21, and fail version check in Kitkat's bcinfo as seen in logcat.

Fix is submitted and will be available in NDK r10e or later: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/124641

Comment: That explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate property you need to set for the Renderscript API version to target.  If you wish to target API 19, then edit your `project.properties` file and add these:

```
renderscript.target=19
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

That will build your Renderscript binaries for API 19 and fall back to a compatible bitcode version if it is run on a different version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that I had tried this as well and it doesn't solve the problem. I've updated the question.

Comment: I don't see an update to the question.  It shows that only the main target API was set, not the renderscript target.

Comment: Ah sorry. I commented before writing the update... should have done that the other way around. It's updated now.

Comment: Try removing the `renderscript.mode.support=true` line but leave in the `renderscript.target` line.

Comment: That gets it building, but I get the same crash. Also, I believe it's pulling in the correct libRSSupport.so when I do it Android.mk because I see this output from `ndk-build`: "[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libRSSupport.so <= <NDK>/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/rs/"